# MYSQL : what kind of join should i use here?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to display all books which their author name starts with J.
but i have two tables : the table Book ( has the book name and the author ID(FK))
and the Author table ( has Author ID (PK))
I used this Code to join them but it keeps giving me errors:

```
select BookID,Name
from Books_Mozon as us
join Author_Mozon as re
where re.Name like'J%';
```

PLEASE help me and thank you !

Comment: Please edit your question and add your errormessage.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using? Please tag **only** the DBMS you're using.

Comment: If you had an author whose name began with a `J` but for some reason had no books in the `Books_Mozon` table, would you still want to see that author's name?

Answer (score 0):

You should use right join because you want all authors starting with J irrespective of other common details in both the tables and the majority information of authors would be present in authors table.

```
 select us.BookID,re.Name
from Books_Mozon as us
right join Author_Mozon as re
on
    us.AuthorID=re.AuthorID
   where re.Name like'J%';
```

Comment: now it gives this error      ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 're.BookID' in 'on clause'

Comment: This is because I assumed foreign key is BookId. Check what is authors table key. Which fields are common between authors and the other table

Comment: Books_Mozon has BookID as Primery Key and AuthorID as foreign key , Authour_Mozon has AuthorID as Primary key And it has a column Name that has the names of the authors..

Comment: Change bookid to authorid ive updated  run if it works noe

Comment: The OP wants to display all *books* whose author's name begins with `J`. If there happens to be an author in the database whose name begins with a `J` for which there are no books represented in the `Books_Mozon` table, then using the right join will result in a `bookID` that is `NULL`. Either the original question was poorly phrased and the OP really doesn't care about books at all (but then why not just look at the `Author_Mozon` table) or this is *not* what the OP wants. I don't think you want to use anything other than an inner join so that you get *only* actual books retrieved.